# GA4 API is not returning data

Tags: google-analytics-4

We have an SEO reporting system where we use the GA4 API, but the information is not returning. We used the website https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/query-explorer/ to identify the issue, but we couldn't resolve it.

We tried to identify any errors in the code or in the data flow, but nothing was found. We would like the report to start working again, retrieving information from the GA4 API for our system.